# What is this error message about? "Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services."

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have seen this warning a couple of time in my event logs. What is it about?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service
Date:          3/5/2015 3:42:41 AM
Event ID:      1530
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      WIN-PLMLT7HVCLA
Description:
Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.  

 DETAIL - 
 3 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-706802955-1937592414-2814065649-500:
Process 1940 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wbem\WmiPrvSE.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-706802955-1937592414-2814065649-500\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
Process 1164 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-706802955-1937592414-2814065649-500\Printers\DevModePerUser
Process 1940 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wbem\WmiPrvSE.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-706802955-1937592414-2814065649-500\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service" Guid="{89B1E9F0-5AFF-44A6-9B44-0A07A7CE5845}" />
    <EventID>1530</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-03-05T03:42:41.877822300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>13112</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{5AC3FF64-02DF-0000-F5CB-C45ADF02D001}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="792" ThreadID="4548" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>WIN-PLMLT7HVCLA</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData Name="EVENT_HIVE_LEAK">
    <Data Name="Detail">3 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-706802955-1937592414-2814065649-500:
Process 1940 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wbem\WmiPrvSE.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-706802955-1937592414-2814065649-500\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
Process 1164 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-706802955-1937592414-2814065649-500\Printers\DevModePerUser
Process 1940 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wbem\WmiPrvSE.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-706802955-1937592414-2814065649-500\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```